# How to remove the little bullets/circles at the top of Foundation's Orbit Content Slider?

Tags: slider, zurb-foundation, orbit

In Zurb Foundation's Orbit Content Slider, how can I remove the little bullets/circles at the top that represent how many slides you have (and are also clickable)? I want them gone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bullets/circles at the top in zurb-foundation 5.

So I assume you are using [this type of orbit](http://zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider).

How about try `.orbit-bullets {display: none;}`, somewhere in your css file?

Comment: Thanks...I tried that, but it didn't work. For now, I'm just going to leave them in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data-options attribute in your ul:

```
<ul data-orbit data-options="bullets:false;">
  <li>
    <img src="satelite-orbit.jpg" alt="slide 1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="andromeda-orbit.jpg" alt="slide 2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="launch-orbit.jpg" alt="slide 3" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can also use Javascript:

```
$(document).foundation({
  orbit: {
    timer_speed: 1000,
    bullets: false
  }
});
```

Foundation 5 has more documentation toward the bottom of the [Orbit page](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html).

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter which version of Foundation you are using. As mentioned in the above answer; setting orbit-bullets to display none should work.

example:

```
.orbit-bullets { display: none; }
```

You could also try the following:

```
.orbit-bullets-container { display: none; }
```

If neither of these declarations are working I would guess that the issue lies within your CSS. It would appear that you have either set orbit-bullets to display block somewhere in your stylesheet after you have set them to display none, possibly within a parent div; or you are calling your stylesheet before foundation's CSS and it's being overridden after your declaration. When using any framework, you should call those styles and scripts first; before your application files.

If you could provide an example it shouldn't be difficult to resolve.